# Quotients and products

Tags: general-topology

From the space of real numbers, form the identification space $\Bbb R/\sim$ by identifying $\frac1n\sim~n$, $\forall n$. Describe a typical neighborhood of $0$ on the space $\Bbb R/\sim$. Look at the subset $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(n,n+1)$. I need to show that $0\in \bar A$, but no sequence in $A$ converges to $0$.

Please help. I love math but this topology is not for me..

Comment: This answers only the first part. Consider the usual quotient map $q: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} /\sim$. Then, $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists n$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n}< \epsilon$. So $p^{-1}(- \epsilon, \epsilon)=(- \epsilon, \epsilon) \cup \{ N: N>n \}$. This is certanly not open in $\mathbb{R}$ (with usual topology) so there are no (open) neighbours of 0 in $\mathbb{R} /\sim$, except the entire space itself.

Comment: @dado: They are talking about open neighbourhoods of $0$ in the quotient space $\mathbb{R} / \mathord{\sim}$ (as a topological space in its own right).

Comment: @Arthur Fischer. I slightly misinterpreted the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give some observations/hints that should direct you.  I will use the following notations:

- $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1 , 2 , \ldots \}$.
- $q$ will denote the quotient mapping $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} / \mathord{\sim}$;
- for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ I'll denote by $\hat{n}$ the $\sim$-equivalence class of $n$ (*i.e.*, $\hat{n} = \{ \frac 1n , n \}$).

**Q1:** If $U \subseteq \mathbb{R} / \mathord{\sim}$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$, then $q^{-1} [ U ]$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  This means that there is an $ \epsilon > 0$ such that $( - \epsilon , + \epsilon ) \subseteq q^{-1} [ U ]$.  Note that given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\hat{n} \in U$ iff $n \in q^{-1} [ U ]$ iff $\frac 1n \in q^{-1} [ U ]$.

**Q2:** Completing the description to Q1 should make this quite easy.

**Q3:**  Suppose $\langle x_n \rangle_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $A$ converging to $0$.  Note that $\mathbb{R} / \mathord{\sim}$ is Hausdorff, and therefore $0$ is the *only* cluster point of the sequence.  It follows that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : | x_n - n | \leq \frac 12 \}$ is finite.  Use this to construct an open neighbourhood of $0$ containing no points of the sequence.

---

***Added (3 March 2013)***

The following image is a visualisation of the space in question.

[image: Quotient space]

The "jags" at the bottom of the image are supposed to represent the intervals $[ n , n + 1 ]$ (moving right-to-left).  The open neighbourhoods of the points $\hat{n} = \{ n , \frac 1n \}$ look essentially like this.

[image: open neighbourhood of n~1/n]

Note that it must contain a part of the interval around $\frac 1n$ and also a part of the jags from $n-1$ to $n$ and also from $n$ to $n+1$ (the latter corresponds to the preimage under the quotient mapping being an open set containing $n$).

As the numbers $\frac 1n$ get arbitrarily close to $0$, so, too, do the jags.  However the jags are also "big" in the sense that neighbourhoods of $0$ do not necessarily include any of them as a subset, as illustrated in the following image.

[image: open neighbourhood of zero]

Of course, your standard open neighbourhood of $0$ in this space doesn't have to look as clean as this.

Comment: @ Arthur Thank for your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that the open neighborhood of 0 in the identification space is the whole space. Is this right? How do I know that open nbd of 0 in R maps to nbd of 0 in the identification space,this should be trivial but it is not clicking?

Comment: @Klara: No, the open nbhds of $0$ are (quite) a bit more subtle.  Perhaps another important point is that if $U\subseteq\mathbb R /\mathord{\sim}$ is open and contains $\hat n$, then there are $\delta,\epsilon>0$ such that $(\frac 1n-\delta,\frac 1n+\delta ),(n-\epsilon,n+\epsilon)\subseteq q^{-1}[U]$, however there is no need that $\delta=\epsilon$. You should be able to use this to show that open nbhds of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ _do not_ necessarily map to open nbhds of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathord{\sim}$.

Comment: @ Arthur Thank you for all your hard work. I think, I understand the neighborhood of 0 now.Let me try to state it. A neighborhood of zero is a union of (-ϵ, +ϵ) with infinitely many areas of "jugs" that are very close to zero and only the part that crosses the R axes are part of  the neighborhood of zero.